# infering Items type using "type" prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a ListItemContainer component that takes `items` and `renderItem` props which are arrays and a function to render each item respectfully.

```js
type ListItemContainerProps = {
items: T;
renderItem: (item: T) => JSX.Element
}
```

What I'm trying to do is get rid of the `renderItem` function and add `type` which is `keyof` an object of components that I use on the renderItem function for each type of item.

```js
type ListTypes = {
note: NoteItem;
tag: TagItem;
folder: FolderItem  
}

type ListItemContainerProps<Type, TItem> =  {
type: Type;
items: TItem[];
}

const ListItemContainer = <T extends keyof ListTypes>({
  type,
  items,
}: ListItemContainerProps<
  T,
  T extends keyof ListTypes ? ListTypes[T] : never
>) => {

const Component = getListWrapper(type)


  return (
    <ul>
      {items.map((item) => (
        <Component key={item.id} item={item} />
    </ul>
    )
}
```

This is the `getListWrapper` function

```js
type ListWrappers = {
  note: typeof NoteComponent;
  folder: typeof FolderComponent;
  tag: typeof TagComponent;
};

const listWrappers = {
  note: NoteComponent,
  folder: FolderComponent,
  tag: TagComponent,
};

export type ListType = keyof ListWrappers;

type Props =
  | ComponentProps<typeof NoteItem>
  | ComponentProps<typeof FolderItem>
  | ComponentProps<typeof TagItem>;

export const getListWrapper = (type: ListType) => (props: Props) => {
  const Component = listWrappers[type] as (props: Props) => JSX.Element;

  if (!Component) {
    throw new Error(`No wrapper found for type: ${type}`);
  }

  return <Component {...props} />;
};
```

---

My problem is if inside the `ListItemContainer` I do

```
if (type === 'note') {
  // Only note has this prop
  items[0].isPinned // note props don't exist, only shared `Item` props exist
}
```

Even though if I tried to use the component like this gives an error

```
<ListItemContainer type="note" items={tags} /> // Error tags array is not assignable to type NoteItem
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

Create additional functions like

```
const isNote = (item: unknown, type: ListType): item is ListWrappers['note'] => {
  return type === 'note';
};
```

and then use it in your condition

```
if (isNote(item, type)) {
  item.isPinned // item type is now what you expected
}
```